# Does the rate of heat addition to a thermodynamic system affect its final state?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, reversibility

I have read that the entropy change of a system is greater than or equal to the integral of the heat added to it divided by its temperature. The case where entropy is equal to the integral is when the heat is reversibly added, i.e., through an infinitesimal temperature difference and by implication, an infinitesimal heat transfer rate. I assume the greater the temperature difference, and thus the greater the heat transfer rate, the greater the entropy change of the system.

Additionally, the heat added at constant pressure is equal to $mC_pdT$, so that for a given amount of heat addition and constant mass, there is a definite temperature change.

Now, consider a cylinder-piston setup. In one case we add heat very slowly (reversibly), and in another we add the heat fast (irreversibly). In both cases, we add the same amount of heat and do so at constant pressure, so that the final temperature and pressure are the same in both cases. The initial and final state variables are therefore the same between the two cases, including the entropy, however in the slow case heat is added reversibly and in the other case irreversibly.

So, I am confused, because I am told that rate of heat addition can affect the entropy of a system, but I cannot see how in my thought experiment. I was hoping someone might help me clear this up.
Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between reversible and irreversible heat transfer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/544634/difference-between-reversible-and-irreversible-heat-transfer)

Comment: Why do you feel like the higher the temperature difference and the heat transfer rate, the larger the entropy change, even if the final states are the same?

Comment: @ChetMiller I am posing the question without knowing if the final states are the same. The only thing I know in this experiment is that the heat added in both cases (reversible and irreversible) is the same, but with different rates. I assume that higher heat transfer rate equals higher entropy change by virtue of the limiting case: infinitesimally slow heat addition results in the least increase in entropy.

Comment: What if I told you that the only thing that really matters to the entropy change is the initial and final states, irrespective of how fast or how slow heat is added to the system?  What if I told you that even in an adiabatic irreversible  process, where no heat is either added to the system, the entropy can increase?

Answer (score 2):

Let's go through some things you say and clean them up:

> I assume the greater the temperature difference, and thus the greater the heat transfer rate, the greater the entropy change of the system.

As you say, under reversible conditions the entropy change is
$$
  \Delta S_{12}=\int_{T_1}^{T_2} \frac{dQ}{T}
$$
where $T_1$ and $T_2$ are the initial and final temperatures. We cannot quite relate the magnitude of $\Delta S_{12}$ to the magnitude of $\Delta T$, as we can see from the $TS$ graph below:
[image]
As you can see, we can construct various paths between the same end temperatures with any $\Delta S$ we wish, positive or negative.

Secondly, the temperature difference $T_2-T_1$ does not say anything about the *rate* of heating. This rate depends, among many other things,  on the difference between the temperature of the system and the temperature of the source that is used to heat up the system.

So, the temperature difference says nothing about the magnitude of the $\Delta S$ and nothing about whether heating is fast or slow.

Now to reversible (slow) versus irreversible (fast) heating: if we heat fast, the pressure of the system  will likely increase first before it finally equalizes with the pressure of the surroundings. In this case $Q\neq \Delta H$, because this equation assumes constant pressure, which we don't have. To calculate heat in this case we need more information about the details of the process. Regardless, we can be certain about one thing: the same amount of heat will lead to *different* final states under slow or fast heating.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer @Themis. I was thinking that for the same exact setup and method of heating, in order to produce a higher heat transfer rate I would need a greater temperature difference between my system and whatever I am using (reservoir) to heat my system. In that way, temperature difference between reservoir and system is related to heat transfer rate. Following on from that, the path with lowest entropy change would be the one with the smallest temperature difference, i.e., slowest rate of heating. Please let me know if you disagree. Your final statement is interesting.

Comment: @pa_blo That's correct: to exchange heat reversibly we need to match the temperature of the source to the temperature of the system. This if course makes transfer extremely slow. As for my final statement, remember that an irreversible process results in some $S_\text{gen}$ because the universe ends up at some different final state ...not enough space to be more detailed

Answer (score 0):

Consider heat added to the piston/cylinder system.  $Q - W = \Delta U$ where $Q$ is the heat added to the system, $W$ is the work done by the system, and $\Delta U$ is the change in internal energy of the system.

For $Q$ added reversibly (slowly), $W$ is less than for the same amount of heat added irreversibly (rapidly), so the change in internal energy for the irreversible process is greater that the change in internal energy for the reversible process.

If the system contains an ideal gas, the internal energy is a function of temperature alone, so the final state for the irreversible case has a higher temperature than for the reversible case.

The same heat added to the system results in less work done by the system for the irreversible case.

The final entropy of the gas is greater for the irreversible case than for the reversible case for the same heat added.  See [Difference between reversible and irreversible heat transfer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/544634/difference-between-reversible-and-irreversible-heat-transfer) on this exchange.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and provided link, @John. If I understood correctly: For the irreversible case, the system has a higher final temperature and less work done than the reversible case. If both cases are isobaric, both cases have the same initial and final pressure. Finally, if the irreversible case has lower work done, then the final volume must be less than the reversible case, assuming W = PdV. This leaves us with Prev = Pirrev, Trev<Tirrev, and Vrev>Virrev. This is incongruent with the equation of state, PV = RT, since for equal P and greater T, V must be greater, not less. Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand your claim that $W$ is necessarily less for the reversible case. If I heat the system first by $Q$ (reversibly or irreversibly) and then wait to extract work $W$ later, how would the system remember the circumstances by which $Q$ was added?

Comment: For same heat added, viscous effects appear in irreversible process and increase temperature compared to reversible process and this reduces work done by system.  You could then (later) extract work by heat transfer but heat cannot be completely converted to work by second law.  Also, see answer to https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/484605/work-done-by-reversible-and-irreversible-process